# Using FOR loop and IF for BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull out the meta description of a few webpages. Below is my code:

```
URL_List = ['https://digisapient.com', 'https://dataquest.io']
Meta_Description = []

for url in URL_List:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    #lower_response_text = response.text.lower()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    metas = soup.find_all('meta')
    for m in metas:
        if m.get ('name') == 'description':
            desc = m.get('content')
            Meta_Description.append(desc)
        else:
            desc = "Not Found"
            Meta_Description.append(desc)
```

Now this is returning me the below:

```
['Not Found',
 'Not Found',
 'Not Found',
 'Not Found',
 'Learn Python, R, and SQL skills. Follow career paths to become a job-qualified data scientist, analyst, or engineer with interactive data science courses!',
 'Not Found',
 'Not Found',
 'Not Found',
 'Not Found']
```

I want to pull the `content` where the meta `name == 'description'`. In case, the condition doesn't match, i.e., the page doesn't have meta property with `name == 'description` it should return `Not Found`.

Expected Output:

```
['Not Found',
 'Learn Python, R, and SQL skills. Follow career paths to become a job-qualified data scientist, analyst, or engineer with interactive data science courses!']
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me know if this works for you!

```
URL_List = ['https://digisapient.com', 'https://dataquest.io']
Meta_Description = []
meta_flag = False

for url in URL_List:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    meta_flag = False
    #lower_response_text = response.text.lower()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    metas = soup.find_all('meta')
    for m in metas:
        if m.get ('name') == 'description':
            desc = m.get('content')
            Meta_Description.append(desc)
            meta_flag = True
            continue
    if not meta_flag:
        desc = "Not Found"
        Meta_Description.append(desc)
```

The idea behind the code is that it will iterate through all the item in `metas`, if a 'description' is found, it will set the flag to be True, thereby skipping the subsequent if-statement. If after iterating through `metas` and nothing is found, it will then append "Not Found" to `Meta_Description`.

Comment: It's giving an error `name 'meta_flag' is not defined`.

Comment: I'm not having that error, but i edited the answer to declare `meta_flag = False` in line 3, see if that solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually what it's supposed to be.

### Your current code

Let's have a look.

```py
for url in URL_List:
```

For each page in your list,

```py
    metas = soup.find_all('meta')
```

you want **all** the `<meta>` tags (regardless of other attributes).

```py
    for m in metas:
```

For each `<meta>` tag, check if it's a `<meta name="description">`. If it is, save its `content`; otherwise, save `"Not Found"`.

HTML `<meta>`

See more info on [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). In short, you can use `<meta>` for more *meta* needs, and as such, you can have multiple `<meta>` tags in your HTML document.

### Your URLs

If you actually open up your URLs and have a look at the `HTML`, you'll see that you get

#### digisapient (1 `<meta>`)

```html
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

#### dataquest (a lot more `<meta>`s)

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Learn Python, R, and SQL skills. Follow career paths to become a job-qualified data scientist, analyst, or engineer with interactive data science courses!" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1" />
    <meta name="bingbot" content="index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Learn Data Science Online and Build Data Skills with Dataquest" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Learn Python, R, and SQL skills. Follow career paths to become a job-qualified data scientist, analyst, or engineer with interactive data science courses!" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.dataquest.io/" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Dataquest" />
    <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/dataquestio" />
    <meta property="article:modified_time" content="2020-05-14T22:43:29+00:00" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.dataquest.io/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dataquest-learn-data-science-logo.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1040" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="520" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@dataquestio" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@dataquestio" />
```

As you can see, the second website has many more such tags in its content, and for every one of those, you go through that last `if/else` statement; if it doesn't have a `name="description"`, you save a `"Not Found"` in your results set.

### Your actual results

To check what your program is doing at a time, and better understand the different values that the variables get over time, I think it's worthwhile to look up debugging and start doing it.

For a quick 'n dirty solution, try writing some messages to the screen as your program's execution progresses, e.g. `Downloaded URL http://...`, `Found 4 <meta> tags`, `Found 0 <meta name="description"`.

I suggest you go over your program line by line, with the HTML in the other hand, and try to see what should happen.

### Getting there

From your expected results, it seems that you don't actually care about the `"Not Found"`s, and you know up front that you always want the `<meta name="description">` tags.

#### With CSS Selectors

You can try selecting DOM elements on your own in the browser, using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Open up your browser's developer tools / JavaScript console and type in, for instance

```js
document.querySelectorAll("meta[name='description']")
```

to get all of the page's `meta` tags with a `name` attribute, which has the value of `description`. See more on [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Having this in mind is important, because
1. you get a better feel of what you're looking at / trying to do
1. you can actually use this type of selectors with `BeautifulSoup`, as well!

#### With BeautifulSoup

So you can move the check for the `name` attribute up in the query. Something like

```py
    metas = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={"name": "description"})
```

and that should give you **only** the tags which have `name=description` in them. This means that all the other `<meta>`s will be ignored.

Alternatively, you can keep the current query method (get all `<meta>`s) and just ignore them in the `if/else` statement, i.e. don't save them in your results list. If you want to know that it's actually *doing* something, but it just doesn't match up you required query, you could simply log a message, instead of saving the `"Not Found"`.

Comment: In case meta description is not found, I need to keep `Not Found` for every URLs.

Comment: In that case, your program is doing what it's supposed to. You're assuming that your HTML will have one and only one `<meta name="description">` tag